# Import from installed @types?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've installed `md5` (also tried `blueimp-md5`) package with corresponding typings like this:

`nmp install --save md5 @types/md5`

`nmp install --save blueimp-md5 @types/blueimp-md5`

When I try to import it like this:

`import { md5 } from '../../../node_modules/md5'`

I get an error: `Module <path> was resolved to <path>/md5.js, but '--allowJs' is not set.`

[image: Error in VS Code]

This makes me think that installed `@types/md5` typings are simply not discovered.
In tsconfig.json I have:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
]
```

So I think it should be detecting typings from `node_modules/@types` folder automatically, but it apparently does not. Exactly same thing with `blueimp-md5` package. The `md5` folder exists in `node_modules/@types` folder, so it has everything in place but still doesn't work.

Visual Studio Code, TypeScript 2, Angular 2 project.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Edit: this is content of @types/md5/index.d.ts file:

```
/// <reference types="node" />

declare function main(message: string | Buffer): string;
export = main;
```

Comment: Is the reference path set in index.d.ts in the typings folder?

Should have a bunch of lines like this: 
/// <reference path="globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />

Comment: @deek please view my edit. This drives me crazy, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the path inside the `node_modules`, it should be:

```
import * as md5 from "md5";
```

The compiler will look for the actual module in the `node_modules`, and will look for the definition files in `node_modules/@types`.

There's a long doc page about it: [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

---

#### Edit

That's because of how the `md5` module is exporting, as it does this:

```
declare function main(message: string | Buffer): string;
export = main;
```

This case is [covered in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require):

> The export = syntax specifies a single object that is exported from
>   the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or
>   enum.
>
> When importing a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import let
>   = require("module") must be used to import the module.

In your case it should be:

```
import md5 = require("md5");
```

---

#### 2nd edit

If you're targetting `es6` then you need to do:

```
const md5 = require("md5");
```

(or `let` or `var` of course).

Comment: When I specify just "md5" it gives error: `Module '"<path>/node_modules/@types/md5/index"' resolves to a non-module entity
 and cannot be imported using this construct.`

Comment: @Titan What is `<path>`? Did you configure your TS to to use node as the module resolution?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: When I use `import md5 = require("md5");` syntax, I get this error: `Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules.`

Comment: Well I ended up using a different module specifically coded for TS, and importing it like this: `import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5'`. But I'm accepting your answer for any future readers.